# How to prove that the complement of a tree with $3$ leaves is not Euler graph?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

> Given a tree $T$ of $n$ vertices which has exactly $3$ leaves prove that complement graph of the tree is not an Euler graph (has Euler circuit).

A tree with exactly $3$ leaves must have exactly one vertex of degree $3$ so as not to violate Handshaking lemma. $T$ also has exactly $3$ vertices of degree $1$ and may have $0$ or more vertices of degree $2$. For example let $T$ be:

[image]

Then $T$'s complement is a triangle and the degrees of all vertices are even so it's Euler!

I guess my thinking is wrong because I'm proving the opposite of what I'm supposed to prove. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you're right, and the quoted problem / result should've excluded that one case. Unless there are other trees which also fail.

Comment: "Then T's complement is a triangle and the degrees of all vertices are even so it's Euler!".  T's complement is a triangle and a single vertex ,it's not Eulerian.

Comment: @W.R.P.S didn't see that! Then because Eulerian graph must be connected this one is not Eurlerian